# Got null reference exception in Loaded event, where the count of SelectedItems in a child datagrid is accessed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, nullreferenceexception, selecteditem

Here is the top of the exception stack:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     at xx.TblQcLotListSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) in ...\InternalEventHandlerQCPage.cs:line 441
     at xx.QCLotListPageLeftLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in ...\InternalEventHandlerQCPage.cs:line 435
```

And this is the mentioned part of the InternalEventHandlerQCPage.cs:

```
    private void QCLotListPageLeftLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.QCPage.QCShowRangesTblHitTest = true;
        this.QCPage.QCShowRangesTblEnabled = true;
        this.QCPage.LOTListRightTxtNameEnabled = false;
        this.QCPage.LOTListFieldEnabled = false;
        this.QCPage.LOTListNumberDateEnabled = false;

        TblQcLotListSelectionChanged(null, null); //line 435
    }

    private void TblQcLotListSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this._QCLotListPageLeftXAML.tblLotList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) //line 441
        {
            this.QCPage.LOTListRightBtnUpEnabled = false;
            this.QCPage.LOTListRightBtnDownEnabled = false;

            this.QCPage.QCShowRangesBtnUpEnabled = false;
            this.QCPage.QCShowRangesBtnDownEnabled = false;

            ...
```

"this" is a UserControl.
_QCLotListPageLeftXAML is also a UserControl used on a page inside a TabControl
tblLotList is a WPF DataGrid
QCPage is a dependency object containing only dependency properties for bindings

We got this exception when the datagrid had 300 items, which is the allowed maximum that we set. The datagrid has 4 columns, so it's not that heavy... Also the software has been running for a while before, so this hasn't occured on the sw start.

Do you have any idea what can go wrong here? SelectedItems can be null for a DataGrid?

Comment: Use the debugger and check step by step which object is not set! Yes, it's no must, that a item is selected

Comment: Tried it, but this error must be "one in a million" or so. Can't reproduce it when I want. :( Of course it happens that no item is selected, but we are talking about SelectedItems here, which is a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was another case when a released, compiled application complained for an other line in the stack than the line which actually caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try, if the error occurs still, when you do this:

```
if (this._QCLotListPageLeftXAML.tblLotList.SelectedItems != null &&
    this._QCLotListPageLeftXAML.tblLotList.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{

}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception. For months it was good, now we experienced this one time without any clue what can be null on that line. This problem can only be solved theoretically. I can't think of anything that can be null there, but if anyone has any idea, please share! :)